# How to create custom tensor value with shape (b,n,m)?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-c++, cppflow

How to create custom tensor value with shape (b,n,m)
I see the cppflow::fill method but it allows inserting 1 value which fills the whole same value in the shape
I see https://github.com/serizba/cppflow/issues/114 but have not found how to fill the value from the custom value or vector for example

I've already created a 2d vector using

```
    vector<vector<float>> tensordata;
  
    for(int i=0; i<cloud->points.size(); i++)
    {
        vector<float> temp;
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            if(j==0)
            {
                temp.push_back(cloud->points[i].x);
            }
            if(j==1)
            {
                temp.push_back(cloud->points[i].y);
            }
            if(j==2)
            {
                temp.push_back(cloud->points[i].z);
            }            
        }
        tensordata.push_back(temp);
    }
```

but still, there's an error to convert it into a tensor.

Comment: https://github.com/serizba/cppflow/issues/187
who's related to this issue, the developer already answered in my issues in his github repo

Answer (score 0):

Create a vector of floats (a 1 dimensional vector, not a vector of vectors).
`vector<float> tensor_data;`

Fill the vector using `tensor_data.push_back()` as if it was 1d data.

Initialize a `cppflow` `tensor` with the right dimensions using the vector.

`cppflow::tensor tnsr = cppflow::tensor(tensor_data, { b, n, m});`

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the answer to this question provided by [GitHub user @serizba](https://github.com/serizba), the author of [`serizba/cppflow`](https://github.com/serizba/cppflow/issues/187) in [issue ticket #187](https://github.com/serizba/cppflow/issues/187)- in particular, in [comment 1087220079](https://github.com/serizba/cppflow/issues/187#issuecomment-1087220079):

> I see. You cannot create a tensor directly from a multidimensional `std::vector`. You must create a flat `std:vector<float>` tensordata, and then convert it to tensor specifying the shape.
>
> In your case, it wouold be something like:
>
> ```cpp
> vector<float> tensordata;
> for(int i=0; i<cloud->points.size(); i++)
> {
>     for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
>     {
>         if(j==0)
>             tensordata.push_back(cloud->points[i].x);
>         if(j==1)
>             tensordata.push_back(cloud->points[i].y);
>         if(j==2)
>             tensordata.push_back(cloud->points[i].z);     
>     }
> }
> auto mytensor = cppflow::tensor(tensordata, {1, cloud->points.size(), 3});
> ```